# Find a node in a Graph that minimizes the distance between two other nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have a directed weighted graph G, with V vertices and E edges. Given two nodes in the graph, let's say A, and B, and given the weight of an edge A-B denoted as w(A, B), I need to find a node C so that max(w(A, C), w(B, C)) is minimal among all possibilities. By possibilities I mean all the values C can take. I don't know if it is completely clear, if it's not, I'll try to be more precise.

Comment: I thought that at first. But since I may have up to 10000 nodes, I think is not suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by w(A, C) you really mean just the weight of an edge, then check all the nodes directly connected to A in turn, for total cost at worst the size of the graph, which is about as good as you could expect, assuming that you always need to read in the graph.

If by w(A, C) you mean the cost of the least cost path from A to C note that most path-finding algorithms, like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm, in fact calculate the cost of the least cost path from A to every other node. You can solve your problem by looking at each node in turn if you have both the costs of getting from A to each node and the costs of getting from each node to B.

So do one run to work out the costs from A to every other node, then reverse the edges in the node and do another run to work out the least cost path from B to every other node in the reversed graph. Then for each node you have the cost of the least cost w(A, C) and the least cost w(C, B) so you can check each node in turn to see which is the best.

If your graph contains cycles, then you need something like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm. If it has negative cycles, you are going to have a problem.

Comment: Yeah. I thing this will perfectly fit my needs. Thank you very much

Comment: I don't think it work. Note that Dijkstra is finding the shortest path, and there is no gurantee you need the shortest path. Look at the counter example: A-(15)-B-(15)-C, and an extra node D where (`w(A,D) = 1`, `w(D,C) = 20`). The shortest path found is `A->D->C`, while the path `A->B->C` minimizes the partial distance, and effectively: `max{w(A,B),w(B,c)} < max{w(A,D),w(D,C)}`. Maytbe there is some modification ti dijkstra, but it is not trivial - and the trivial "run dijkstra" fails here.

Comment: You're right. I'll see if I can modify Dijkstra in some way. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Andrés: I *think* the modification you are after is Floyd-Warashall all pairs shortest path algorithm. I tried to elaborate in my answer, hope it is helpful.

Comment: The algorithm I described gets the correct answer on your example graph. I will use your lettering: you seem to be using A and C as the end nodes, whereas the original problem uses A and B as the end nodes. It runs Dijkstra twice. The first run finds that B, C, and D are distance 15, 21, and 1 from A. The second run finds that A, B, and D are distance 21, 15, and 20 from C. It then looks at the pairs of distances computed for B and D and finds that B with 15 and 15 is better than D with 1 and 20.

Comment: Your comment clarifies it. I misunderstood what you meant in your solution. apologizes. Please clarify it in the answer itself and edit it so I can turn my downvote into an upvote!

Comment: @Andrés: Note that the edit clears any suspecion from the answer, I believe it should work and you should consider accepting the answer if you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Not extremely clear what you asking, but here is one method for weighted distances:
Treat it like a distance problem in R^n, where the actual rectilinear distance from C in any dimension is multiplied by the weight of that dimension of the path to obtain weighted distance. Make the entire expression the sum of the weighted distances and use the second-derivative test for maximization of this expression.

Cheers,
Andrew